# React Native Expo Camera Ratio and Preview not configurable enough?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-camera

[image: Android Snapchat App]
[image: My Android App]

Hello all,
I have looked at a lot of other posts related to this issue but my question isn't simply how to put the correct preview dimensions based on the aspect ratio chosen. Im trying to figure out how Snapchat is able to consistently have a full screen camera preview expanding all the way from the status bar to the bottom of the screen. Ive used `const ratios = await cameraRef.current.getSupportedRatiosAsync()` to get the aspect ratios available for my test device and the highest one is 16:9, which doesn't give me enough height to have a preview that covers the entire screen and doesn't look distorted and out of the ordinary. In the android OS camera app theres an aspect ratio called 'full' which takes all the realestate available on the screen to show the camera preview, but the aspect ratios **getSupportedRatiosAsync()** returns do not include this 'full' aspect ratio. Im trying to achieve this flush look where the camera preview takes the entire screen height available and does not distort, but I end up having the black bar at the bottom because I have to take into account the aspect ratio of the camera and put the height of the preview acordingly. Is there something i'm missing here? When I simply put a flex:1 for the camera preview it takes over the screen but it ends up being a distorted preview because it's not fitting the aspect ratio of the camera.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    Modal,
    ImageBackground,
    Animated,
    BackHandler,
} from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

//expo camera
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'

//expo AV
import { Video, AVPlaybackStatus } from 'expo-av'

//custom components
import HeaderX from '../components/HeaderX'
import CameraButton from '../components/CameraButton'

//ionicons
import { Entypo, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
//ionicons

//colors
import colors from '../constants/colors'

//safe area
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

//redux
import { takePicture } from '../store/camera/actions'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// MediaLibrary
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library'

//gesture handlers
import {
    PinchGestureHandler,
    PinchGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
    State,
    TapGestureHandler,
    TapGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import Reanimated, {
    Extrapolate,
    interpolate,
    useAnimatedGestureHandler,
    useAnimatedProps,
    useSharedValue,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    runOnJS,
    runOnUI,
} from 'react-native-reanimated'

//nav 5
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'

//status bar
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')
console.log(' ~ file: CameraScreen.js ~ line 68 ~ height', height)
console.log(' ~ file: CameraScreen.js ~ line 68 ~ width', width)

const CameraScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    let checkMarkSet = null
    if (route.params) {
        checkMarkSet = true
    }

    // RATIO SETTER
    const [imagePadding, setImagePadding] = useState(0)
    const [ratio, setRatio] = useState('4:3') // default is 4:3
    const screenRatio = height / width
    const [isRatioSet, setIsRatioSet] = useState(false)
    async function prepareRatio() {
        let desiredRatio = '4:3' // Start with the system default
        // This issue only affects Android
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            const ratios = await cameraRef.current.getSupportedRatiosAsync()
            let distances = {}
            let realRatios = {}
            let minDistance = null
            for (const ratio of ratios) {
                const parts = ratio.split(':')
                const ratioHeight = parseInt(parts[0])
                const ratioWidth = parseInt(parts[1])
                const realRatio = ratioHeight / ratioWidth
                realRatios[ratio] = realRatio
                // ratio can't be taller than screen, so we don't want an abs()
                const distance = screenRatio - realRatio
                distances[ratio] = realRatio
                if (minDistance == null) {
                    minDistance = ratio
                } else {
                    if (distance >= 0 && distance < distances[minDistance]) {
                        minDistance = ratio
                    }
                }
            }
            // set the best match
            desiredRatio = minDistance

            //  calculate the difference between the camera width and the screen height
            const remainder = Math.floor(
                (height - realRatios[desiredRatio] * width) / 2
            )

            // set the preview padding and preview ratio
            setImagePadding(remainder / 2)
            console.log(`okay look ${remainder / 2}`)
            setRatio(desiredRatio)
            // Set a flag so we don't do this
            // calculation each time the screen refreshes
            setIsRatioSet(true)
        }
    }

    const setCameraReady = async () => {
        if (!isRatioSet) {
            await prepareRatio()
        }
    }
    // RATIO SETTER

    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back)
    const [activateCamera, setActivateCamera] = useState(false)
    const [video, setVideo] = useState('')
    const [showVideoModal, setShowVideoModal] = useState(false)
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets()

    useFocusEffect(() => {
        if (navigation.isFocused()) {
            setActivateCamera(true)
        }
    })

    const [pic, setPic] = useState(null)

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

    const cameraRef = useRef()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [zooming, setZooming] = useState(0)

    //camera settings
    const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState('off')

    // const picTaken = useSelector((state) => state.cameraReducer.pictureUri)
    // console.log(
    //     ' ~ file: CameraScreen.js ~ line 36 ~ CameraScreen ~ picTaken',
    //     picTaken
    // )

    // camera Functions
    async function takePictureHandler() {
        try {
            if (cameraRef.current) {
                const options = {
                    quality: 0.5,
                    base64: true,
                    skipProcessing: true,
                }
                let photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options)
                setPic(photo.uri)
                dispatch(takePicture(photo.uri))
                setShowModal(true)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }

        // setPickedImage(image.uri)
        // props.onImageTaken(image.uri)
    }

    function flipCameraHandler() {
        setType(
            type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                : Camera.Constants.Type.back
        )
    }

    function flashSwitchHandler() {
        if (flashMode === 'off') {
            setFlashMode('on')
        }
        if (flashMode === 'on') {
            setFlashMode('off')
        }
    }

    async function savePictureLocallyHandler(localUri) {
        const { status } = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync()
        if (status === 'undetermined') {
            const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync()
            if (status === 'granted') {
                const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri)
            }
        }

        if (status === 'granted') {
            const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri)
            if (asset) {
                //display check mark showing it was saved.
            }
        }

        if (status === 'denied') {
            console.log('Open settings and give permission')
        }
    }

    // zoom gesture handler
    const zoom = useSharedValue(0)
    const MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR = 20
    const SCALE_FULL_ZOOM = 20
    const formatMaxZoom = 1
    const maxZoomFactor = Math.min(formatMaxZoom, MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR)
    const neutralZoomScaled = (neutralZoom / maxZoomFactor) * formatMaxZoom
    const maxZoomScaled = (1 / formatMaxZoom) * maxZoomFactor

    const neutralZoom = 0
    useAnimatedProps(
        () => ({
            zoom: interpolate(
                zoom.value,
                [0, neutralZoomScaled, 1],
                [0, neutralZoom, maxZoomScaled],
                Extrapolate.CLAMP
            ),
        }),
        [maxZoomScaled, neutralZoom, neutralZoomScaled, zoom]
    )

    function updateValue() {
        setZooming(zoom.value)
    }

    function willThisWork() {
        'worklet'
        runOnJS(updateValue)()
    }

    const onPinchGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
        onStart: (_, context) => {
            context.startZoom = zoom.value
        },
        onActive: (event, context) => {
            // trying to map the scale gesture to a linear zoom here
            const startZoom = context.startZoom ?? 0
            const scale = interpolate(
                event.scale,
                [1 - 1 / SCALE_FULL_ZOOM, 1, SCALE_FULL_ZOOM],
                [-1, 0, 1],
                Extrapolate.CLAMP
            )
            zoom.value = interpolate(
                scale,
                [-1, 0, 1],
                [0, startZoom, 1],
                Extrapolate.CLAMP
            )
            willThisWork()
        },
    })

    // VIDEO RECORDING
    async function beginRecording() {
        console.log('started')
        let video = await cameraRef.current.recordAsync()
        setVideo(video)
        // setPic(photo.uri)
        // dispatch(takePicture(photo.uri))
    }

    async function endRecording() {
        console.log('ended')
        cameraRef.current.stopRecording()
        setShowVideoModal(true)
    }

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                ...styles.container,
                // paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? insets.top : null,
            }}
        >
            <StatusBar
                style=""
                translucent
                backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,255,0)"
            />
            <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPinchGesture}>
                <Reanimated.View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: 'back',
                        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                        paddingBottom: imagePadding * 4,
                    }}
                >
                    {activateCamera && (
                        <Camera
                            style={{
                                // marginTop: imagePadding,
                                // marginBottom: imagePadding,
                                flex: 1,
                                // height: 733,
                            }}
                            ref={cameraRef}
                            type={type}
                            flashMode={flashMode}
                            zoom={zooming}
                            onCameraReady={setCameraReady}
                            ratio={ratio}
                            maxDuration={10000}
                            autoFocus="on"
                        >
                            <View
                                style={[
                                    styles.contentContainer,
                                    {
                                        paddingTop: insets.top,
                                        paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
                                        top: insets.top,
                                        bottom: insets.bottom,
                                    },
                                ]}
                            >
                                <View style={styles.topLeftCont}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={flipCameraHandler}
                                    >
                                        <Entypo
                                            name="loop"
                                            size={27}
                                            color="white"
                                            style={styles.flipIcon}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={flashSwitchHandler}
                                    >
                                        <Ionicons
                                            name={
                                                flashMode !== 'off'
                                                    ? 'flash'
                                                    : 'flash-off'
                                            }
                                            size={27}
                                            color="white"
                                            style={styles.cameraSettingsButton}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>

                                <CameraButton
                                    style={{
                                        ...styles.floatingPlusCont,
                                        left: width / 2 - 45,
                                    }}
                                    onLongPress={beginRecording}
                                    onEndPress={endRecording}
                                    onTap={takePictureHandler}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </Camera>
                    )}
                </Reanimated.View>
            </PinchGestureHandler>
 )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
    },
    camera: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },

    topLeftCont: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 45,
        top: 0,
        right: 10,
        borderRadius: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(184,184,184,0.42)',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        // flexDirection: 'row',
        padding: 5,
    },
    flipIcon: {
        marginVertical: 7,
        transform: [
            {
                rotate: '90deg',
            },
        ],
    },
    cameraSettingsButton: { marginVertical: 7 },
    modal: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    },
    takenImage: { flex: 1 },
    bottomCont: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: 10,
    },
    bottomButtonsCont: {
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    floatingPlusCont: {
        bottom: 25,
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 90,
        height: 90,
        borderRadius: 45,
    },
    loadingView: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
})

export default CameraScreen
```

Comment: long overdue but maybe just set the height of the preview to the height of the screen and the width according to the aspect ratio you want, allowing it to overflow?